# SQL Setting Variable for Current Year Month by Combining two VarChar fields using case statement

Tags: t-sql, variables, case, varchar, declare

I am trying to declare a variable for the current year and month based on a field called YEARMO.

It's a 6 character varchar field with the first 4 characters representing the year and the next 2 characters representing the month (ex. February 2018 as 201802).

I need the month variable to have a 0 in front of it if is a month that only has one digit (any month before October). Current code returns '20182' and would like it to return '201802'.

```
declare @current_month varchar(6)

set @current_month = CAST( year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) 
+ case when  len(CAST( month(getdate()) as varchar(2))) < 1 then '0' + 
CAST( month(getdate()) as varchar(2)) 
else CAST( month(getdate()) as varchar(2))
end

select @current_month;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is over complicated. Use `right` instead:

```
declare @current_month char(6)
set @current_month = CAST( year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + right('00' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)), 2)
select @current_month;
```

Result:

```
201802
```

If you really want to use `case` instead, you should change the `1` to `2`:

```
set @current_month = CAST( year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + 
                     case when len(CAST(month(getdate()) as varchar(2))) < 2 then 
                     '0' + CAST( month(getdate()) as varchar(2)) else 
                     CAST( month(getdate()) as varchar(2)) end
```

Comment: @antman actually, Uzi's answer is better than mine, though the padding technique is a good thing to know about.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Convert` function if you are looking for current month

```
select convert(char(6), getdate(), 112)
```

Comment: I should have thought about it when writing my answer :-) +1.

Answer (score 0):

declare @current_month varchar(6)

set @current_month = CAST(year(getdate())*100 + month(getdate()) as varchar(6))