# Variable for date based on last table update - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I'm trying to create a date variable based on the last run date of a table, "b." That is, a 4 month lag from the date fetched by this query:

```
select top 1 rundate from b
```

It produces the date '202003.'

This is my code that is attempting to produce the variable date:

```
declare @four_month_lag_from_table_update varchar (6)

set @four_month_lag_from_table_update = CAST( year((select top 1 rundate from b)) as varchar(4)) + 
right('00' + (select top 1 rundate from b)-4, 2)

select @four_month_lag_from_table_update
```

I get the error code 
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Expected result is 4 months prior to last run date, so if last run date is 202003 expected result is 201911.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1) **Do not ever** use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`.
2) Please post a sample data and expected results.

Comment: 202003 is NOT a date. That's your first problem. But the year function requires a date (or similar) argument. Can you cast a value like '202003' to date? But you've already done this in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770533/sql-setting-variable-for-current-year-month-by-combining-two-varchar-fields-usin) years ago - the same logic applies here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "last" rundate, use `order by` or aggregation functions:

```
select @rundate = max(rundate)
from b;
```

Your "date" sounds like a string.  If you want to get four months before convert to a date and convert back:

```
select @rundate = format(dateadd(month, -4,
                                 max(convert(date, concat(rundate, '01')))
                                ), '%y%M'
                        )
from b;
```